# Making a 2/4 channel buzzer with light

Tags: switches

I am making a project, basically consisting of 4 bulbs and 4 switches.
I want to make it such a way that when either of the 1 switch is pressed 1 bulb should glow. The bulb which glows should be the one pressed first. Once pressed, the other switches should be unable to operate.

Comment: Thank you for the information, good luck with it. Or did you have a question? If so: Please realise that this is not a free design
house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied
out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question
shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your
post doesn't, I'm afraid. Please revise your question showing your work and
findings so far, in considerable detail.

Comment: 4 switches, yet you say "when either of the 1 switch"... You need to sort this out.

Comment: You are looking for a "quiz lights schematic". Off to Google and do an image search ...

Answer (score 0):

AND1, NOR1, NOR2 are the basic cell you need. AND2 needs to have as many inputs as there are flip-flops. NOR1 and NOR2 are an RS flip flop and AND1 is an enable gate which only transfers the SET input as long all flip flops are in reset (enable lines all high).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8oVIb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>